# IIS not loading .scss files

Tags: css, iis

So I've moved my website from XAMPP WebHost to IIS (Internet Information Service), but for some reason, my `site.scss` stylesheet isn't loaded?

[image: scss google]

All .js files is loaded with their content, so I know the paths should work:

```html
<link href="/css/site.scss" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/toggletheme.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/togglemenu.js" defer></script>
```

Folder structure:

[image: folder]

Is there something else that needs to be enabled in the IIS in the `Handler Mappings` or something like that, before the content can be loaded?

The `.scss` file just contains a lot of styling and isn't empty see snip:

[image: scss file]

Comment: you're meant to compile them into css files

Comment: So i need to compile the scss into css? Cant IIS handle that like XAMPP can?

Comment: don't think it can - don't think standard browsers can support scss either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you show is a simple CSS file contains simple variables, can be load by all the latest browsers.
you don't need a ".scss" extension file in "*/css/site.scss*", but a simple ".css" extention does the job as it "*/css/site.css*".